# unlocking bootloader in ZTE blade 7 lite

Tags: fastboot, bootloader, bootloader-lock, zte-blade, zte

i installed all drivers and also extracted adb and fastboot in my system so i enter `"adb reboot bootloader"` code in cmd after changing into adb folder and then when i enter `"fastboot oem unlock"` it respond back `"waiting for any device"` but nothing happends then

also what seems weird is my phone enters to "Meta Mode" and not "Fastboot mode" or something more relevant

Answer (score 1):

**To exit Meta mode**, you would hold the power button down for 10 seconds to force the phone to turn off and then hold the power button to restart the phone

**To enter recovery mode**, press and hold the Power and the Volume Up buttons at the same time then navigate to Fastboot mode by volume keys and enter using power key.

It's not recommended to root if you are a beginner. And even if you attempt to you should stick to a tutorial like [THIS](https://rootmygalaxy.net/twrp-root-zte-blade-v7-lite/) one. Or you may follow some other tutorial.

Use may Magisk it's better than SuperSU. See the link